# Using Spring transaction with custom transaction management logic

Tags: spring-transactions

I have a library with a static factory and some custom transaction management as shown below.

```
MyResourceConnection resource = Factory.getResourceConnection();
resource.startTxn();
Node node = resource.getNodeById(10);
//do some thing on node.
resource.updateNode(node);
resource.commit();
```

The above kind of code works fine for transaction within a single method. 
How can I integrate it with spring transaction management such that there can be transactions over multiple methods?

In other words if I'm writing a JPA alternative with its own way of transaction management, how can I integrate it with spring?

I know it is a broad question, but any pointers to relevant material will be helpful. I did some googling and so far I'm stuck.